# I have four EC2 instances in my AWS but want a new developer to only view and access one which i Tagged

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my AWS environment I have four EC2 instances. I have an external developer who wants to run some codes on one instance and I want this instance to be visible to just the developer and not the other instances.

I created a policy and attached to the user. The policy is shown below. But the developer is not seeing any instance at all. What am i missing?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:af-south-1:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/i-02af5a8f7b185c95e"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/external": "developer"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: By "visible to the developer", I presume you mean that it should be listed in the EC2 console. Unfortunately that's not how the AWS console works - you can't restrict a 'describe' API call such as [DescribeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) to a subset of resources based on their tags.

Comment: O i see. what do you advise.

Comment: You can write a policy that allows EC2 API actions against specific tagged instances (or even against specific instance IDs afaik) which should be sufficient for a developer writing code or running scripts. If the developer needs to use the AWS console then you can also allow ec2:DescribeInstances so that all instances are visible but the developer will still be restricted to API actions on the tagged instances. If the developer doesn't need programmatic access at all but only needs SSH/RDP access, then they don't need any IAM permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you want to restrict the developer's ability to "view and access" the EC2 instances.

**Viewing instances**

The ability to list the instances within the EC2 management console (and via the AWS CLI) is controlled by IAM policies.

However, if you look on [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) for the `DescribeInstances` action, you will notice that the only `Condition` that can be applied to the request is `Region`. It is not possible to control *what* information is actually returned. Therefore, a person can either list *ALL* of the instances or *NONE* of the instances.

**Accessing instances with SSH**

The ability to login to an EC2 instance depends upon *HOW* you login to them.

If you are using `SSH` to connect to an instance, then the user will need to provide a **private key** when logging into the instance (`ssh -i key.pem ...`). Linux systems verify this SSH request by looking in the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to see if there is a matching **public key**. If so, the user is allowed to login.

By default a user called `ec2-user` is created when an Amazon Linux instance is launched. However, you can  [create more users on an EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html#create-user-account) so that they have their own home directory and their own SSH keys. For example, if you create a user called `brown`, then they would login via `ssh -i key.pem brown@1.2.3.4` and Linux will look for their public key in `/home/brown/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

So, the best way to control who can `SSH` into an instance is to have each person use their own **private key** and put the matching **public key** into appropriate `authorized_keys` files. Users can even all use the `ec2-user` login, as long as *their* public key is in the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Note that this method of access is **totally unrelated to AWS IAM**.

**Accessing instances with EC2 Instance Connect**

The EC2 management console has a feature called **EC2 Instance Connect** that:

- Uses AWS IAM permissions to control access to instances
- Offers a web-based SSH service
- Uses *temporary* SSH keys to grant access to an instance

The benefit of EC2 Instance Connect is that you can use AWS IAM to control access and all `.pem` files are managed automatically. You can use IAM Policies to control which users can login to each instance.

See: [Install EC2 Instance Connect on your EC2 instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html)

**Accessing instances with AWS Systems Manager Session Manager**

Known as "the service with the funny name", Session Manager has a totally different way of connect with EC2 instances. It uses an **agent** installed on the instance to communicate back to AWS. Requests to connect are then made via Session Manager rather than using SSH. The benefit of this approach is that it even works with instances in **private subnets** and it **uses IAM Policies** to control access. All access is even logged for security tracking.

You can use IAM Policies to control which individual user can access each instance. No SSH keys are required.

[Connect to your Linux instance with AWS Systems Manager Session Manager - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager-to-linux.html)